# Accessing a local node.js server remotely

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

I have setup a mongoDB collection at

```
192.168.254.254:27017/testDB
```

for example, and on the same computer, I have the nodemon/express server at

```
localhost:3000/ //HTTP commands are routed here
```

How do I access the HTTP commands (GET, POST, etc.) on a different computer when my node server's is just supported locally, or do I have to deploy it online like on Heroku?

Comment: You can use this service https://ngrok.com/, it creates a tunnel to your `localhost`

Comment: To add: Depends on your use case. If you want to code remotely but have your own environment, you could use instead an online IDE such as c9 f.ex.. Else you can just tunnel your requests.

Comment: You can use server system ipaddress like 172.18.xx.xx:3000/